# how to send values from one activity to another extended activity in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-background, android-task

I am developing an application in which I have a common activity, i.e. **BaseActivity**, I am extending it to all other activities in my application. 
I run few AsyncTask in BaseActivity to reflect in all other activities. My query is I need to pass values to this BaseActivity from one of my activities, say **MainActivity**

I tried to Class, Interface concepts, but not working for me. Suggest me, how to achieve this. If any of my reference code needed, comment it, I will post it.

**EDITED**

I need to pass this **countvalue** to **BaseActivity**. I cannot use Intent, because I am navigating to another activity say **MainActivity2**

**MainActivity**
This is my AsyncTask code

```
public class AsyncHttpTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {

    @Override

    protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {

        Integer result = 0;

        try {

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(params[0]));
            int statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                String response = streamToStringCount(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent());
                parseResultCount(response);
                result = 1;
            } else {
                result = 0;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override

    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {

        //  isRefreshing = false;


        //layout.setRefreshing(false);

        super.onPostExecute(result);

    }
}


String streamToStringCount(InputStream stream) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
    String line;
    String result = "";
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

        result += line;
    }
    if (null != stream) {

        stream.close();
    }
    return result;
}


private void parseResultCount(String result) {
    Detail_Item item;
    try {
        JSONObject posts = new JSONObject(result);


        //rstatus1=posts.optString("count");
        countValue=posts.optInt("count");
        countValue1=countValue;
        Log.i("countvalue", String.valueOf(countValue));

    }

    catch (JSONException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

Comment: which type of values you want in base activity?

Comment: Can you show your code what you have tried?

Comment: I am getting few integer values from json in **MainActivity** and need to pass those integer values to **BaseActivity**

Comment: Sure, I will post it. @Masum

Answer (score 1):

store the values in SharedPreferences and retrieve them from any activity in your application.

Comment: Good suggestion. I will try that and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

In your AsyncTask 
define

```
public interface ResultListener {
    void onResultReady(Integer result);
}
```

create constructor which accepts ResultListener parameter

```
private ResultListener mRl = null;
public AsyncHttpTask (ResultListener rl) {
    mRl=rl;
}
```

at postExecute (it runs on main thread, you know) call listener

```
 protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
       super.onPostExecute(result);
       if (mRl!=null)
          mRl.onResultReady(result);
 }
```

Now if you have a reference to some activity which implements ResultListener 
which you need to pass a result you start the task this way:

```
AsyncHttpTask.ResultListener myActivity ;
...
(new AsyncHttpTask(myActivity)).execute(myParameters);
```

Your question now boils down to how your activities/fragments are started and coordinated so that you could get proper `myActivity` reference at proper place.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you want to pass some value from MainActivity(Which is extended BaseActivity) to BaseActivity.

Just create an method in BaseActivity like,

```
protected void setYourValue(Object obj){
    ..........
}
```

From your MainActivity just call this method and set whatever you want.

```
setYourValue("This is my value");
```

If you the MainAcitivity is not extended from BaseActivity,

```
 public static void setYourValue(Object obj){
    ..........
 }
```

In MainActivity,

```
BaseActivity.setYourValue("This is my value");
```

Please do some study on implementing sharedpreferrence.

Comment: I am not extending BaseActivity in MainActivity, so I cannot access `setYourValue` directly, right?

Comment: Ok, If so then no other way i guess, you need to create an static method in BaseActivity or SharedPreference..

Answer (score 0):

In your current Activity, create a new Intent:

```
Intent i = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
i.putExtra("new_variable_name","value");
startActivity(i);
```

Then in the new Activity, retrieve those values:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String value = extras.getString("new_variable_name");
}
```

[Refer Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by defining public static as all the instance of this or subclass will share it. This is really ugly solution which i don't recommend. It better to use Extras

Intent intent = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("Key", Value);
startActivity(intent)

more info consult Doc https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html